# Div content gets 'unsmushed' after window resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div in which I want to toggle a wordpress action hook.

```
<div class="sub-slider">
    <section class="subscriptions_slider container-fluid">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[subscriptions_slider]"); ?>
    </section>
</div>
```

When I load the page, this divs content is all smushed in the center. But if I resize my window back and forth. The content is getting 'fixed'. Why is this? I am not interacting in any other way. How can I fix this?

Comment: The answer to this is hidden in your css somewhere. Not being able to see that means no one can help answer.

Comment: @JakeParis Yeah I thought so to. Problem is that this project has rather large and chaotic css file. What should I look for, what could be causing this? Maybe its not an easy question to answer.

Comment: You would use your developer tools. Inspect the element causing problems and try to see what css is changing when the window changes size.

Comment: @JakeParis unfortunately chrome dev tools does not respond to simply resizing window (press f12 and drag console) :(

Comment: Turn on the dev tools, then press the "mobile" button (all the way on the left next to the pointer button).